# RUN a command in Dockerfile __after__ a linked container is started

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I wish to RUN a command in a container **after** a linked container is started.

Let's say I want to run `php app/console doctrine:schema:create` (or any other application used to pre-populate my database schema ... not necessarily php/symfony but nothing as simple as a sql script which can be RUN *in* the database container) as soon my container is build but obviously **after** the database container has been built and the application volume has been mounted.

The init script is:

- complex -> so the I need the support of something more sophisticated than simple sql or bash script
- slow -> so it needs to be run only once when the container are setup

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
application:
    build: code
    volumes:
         - ./symfony:/var/www/symfony
        - ./logs/symfony:/var/www/symfony/app/logs
    tty: true
db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
        - 3306:3306
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: root
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: longtake
php:
    build: php-fpm
    expose:
        - 9000:9000
    volumes_from:
        - application
    links:
        - db
nginx:
    build: nginx
    ports:
        - 80:80
    links:
        - php
    volumes_from:
        - application
    volumes:
        - ./logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx
```

The relevant `Dockerfile` is the php-fpm/Dockerfile which could be something like:

```
FROM debian:jessie

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get install -y php5-common php5-cli php5-fpm php5-mcrypt php5-mysql php5-apcu php5-gd php5-imagick php5-curl php5-intl

# This should be executed after the application volume is ready
RUN cd /var/www/symfony && php app/console doctrine:schema:create

ADD symfony.ini /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/
ADD symfony.ini /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/

ADD symfony.pool.conf /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

CMD ["php5-fpm", "-F"]

EXPOSE 9000
```

`docker-compose build` returns

```
Step 4 : RUN cd /var/www/symfony && php app/console doctrine:schema:create
 ---> Running in 629ab2771cb3
/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to /var/www/symfony
Service 'php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c cd /var/www/symfony && php app/console doctrine:schema:create' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Comment: You should have a look at the official docker wordpress and the entrypoint script it uses.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `RUN` a command at container runtime. `RUN` works when you create the images.

You can create a small start script, which creates the schema and then it starts php and put it in `CMD`.

Or you can create a small image specifically to create the schema. You run the container, it creates the schema and then just exits.

I'm sure you can put it in compose as well, but I don't know enough about it to post code.